# How do I grep for for a string starting with a dash (as in "-1")?

Tags: bash, grep

I have been trying to search -1 using grep, but i am unable to find the regex required:

I have already tried:

```
grep -1
grep "-1"
grep \-1
grep '-1'
grep /-1/
```

But none of them seem to work. Is there any other way.

Here's what I am seeing:

```
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt
-1
2
3
-1
5
-1
7
-1
-1
-1

Time
taken
=
0
seconds
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt|grep -1
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt|grep "-1"
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt|grep \-1
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt|grep '-1'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt|grep /-1/
@DESKTOP-7QNRLTS:~/CS251/CS251-practice/Ass6$ cat raw.txt|grep 1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

Comment: Please post sample example Input and expected sample output too with what results you are seeing after running commands in your post.

Comment: duplicate would be there somewhere.. you need to use `grep -- '-1'` or `grep '\-1'` ... the `-` is getting interpreted as option

Comment: `cat file.txt | grep foo` can also be written as `grep foo file.txt`.